# Regex that matches any 9 digits except last 4 digits can't be 9999 or 0000

Tags: regex, zip

I am trying to figure out a regular expression that matches any 9 digits, but the last 4 digits can't be 9999 or 0000. For example, I want the regex to match these:

- 123456789
- 123459991
- 123459990

But not these:

- 123450000
- 123459999

I tried negative lookahead. But it doesn't seem to fit in my requirement.

The closest I can get is `\d{5}[^\D90]{4}`, but with this the last 4 digits can't be 0 or 9 at all, which is not what I want.

It is a special zip code requirement. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `\d{5}[^\D90]{4}` regex matches any 5 digits followed by 4 characters other than a non-digit, `9` and `0`.

You can use

```
^(?!\d*(?:9999|0000)$)\d{9}$
```

Shorter variant: `^(?!\d*(?:9{4}|0{4})$)\d{9}$`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW5dY4/2)

The negative lookahead (anchored at the start) will fail the match if the input contains some digits and ends with either `9999` or `0000`.

If we go on optimizing the regex, the *most efficient version* (basing on what [Casimir suggests in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35373764/3832970)) is:

```
^\d{5}(?!9{4}|0{4})\d{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bW5dY4/3)

Here,

- `^` - start of the string
- `\d{5}` - exactly 5 digits
- `(?!9{4}|0{4})` - check (but not match, the index stays after the 5th digit since it is a zero width assertion) if there are exactly 4 `9`s or `0`, and if found, the match is failed (as `(?!...)` is a *negative lookahead*)
- `\d{4}` - exactly 4 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for the demo and explanation. I like your second answer. It is more readable too.

Answer (score 4):

use a negative lookahead after the 5th digit:

```
^[0-9]{5}(?!0000|9999)[0-9]{4}$
```

or a lookbehind at the end:

```
^[0-9]{9}$(?<!0000|9999)
```

(if your regex flavor doesn't allow a lookbehind with an alternation, use two lookbehinds:

```
^[0-9]{9}$(?<!0000)(?<!9999)
```

Comment: It seems that `(0{4}|9{4})` perform better than `(0000|9999)` - limited quantifiers yield less backtracking.